# Rails call another controller's action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, Posts and Comments. I would like to create a button on the Post show view which directs it to Comment new action. So I create a new action in Post:

```
  def comment
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    redirect_to new_comment_path
  end
```

I want to save the post_id in the Comment models, so I create d hidden field in the new comment form:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :body %>
  </div>
```

But error appeared: "Called id for nil".

I am very new, can anyone help? Or should I use other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are missing to pass the value, 
I had tried out this way and it works, for your example.

**edited:**

```
redirect_to :controller=>'comments', :action=>'new_comment', :post_id=>@post.id
```

receive as `@post_id = params[:post_id]`

Comment: Passing object in query string? Bad idea. Pass id instead.

Comment: It gives a routing error: "No route matches {:post_id=>1, :controller=>"comments", :action=>"new_comment"}". I already add this in route:  "resources :posts do
   member do
  get :comment
   end
  end"